# Can not run single KIFTestCase (subclass of XCTestCase)

Tags: ios, testing, xctest, kif, kif-framework

I am new to automated testing.

I try to do automated integration testing of my app with Kif framework to facilitate testing before releases. I have several test cases. When i run testing (Cmd + U) this test cases runs but in strange sequence (not in alphabetically sorted order). I also can not run single test case, when i try to do so random test case runs before test case i want to run.

P.S. Some of my test cases inherit more general test cases.

Can you give me any hints what it can be?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, test cases have no defined order and they should be independent of one another. If you have unit tests that depend on execution order, you're doing testing incorrectly and need to refactor your tests to be independent.